# WSUS - show most recent updates?

Tags: windows, wsus

Using the most recent version of WSUS (Windows Server Update Services) is there a way to determine what the most recently applied updates are for a given machine? Or, when viewing the machine's status report apply some date filtering -- or sorting?

Seems like I've seen this done, but I can't seem to stumble over how.

I'd like to get a list of the updates applied last month for a couple servers.

Comment: reporting anything other than updates needed/with errors is shockingly bad in the more recent wsus.   Because obviously I want to lump in the 20000 odd unapplicable updates with those that I've recently installed?

Comment: Hmm... sad-making. I could've sworn that this would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only a couple of servers you could probably get the info from their local Windows Update logs:

c:\WINDOWS\WindowsUpdate.log

It's not a literal answer to your question, but should solve the problem.

Just search upwards from the bottom of the file for "Title". If you want something automated, you could harvest the log files using a batch file and use findstr to filter the relevant lines. As a proof-of-concept try this command:

```
type %windir%\WindowsUpdate.log | findstr "Title"
```

Comment: That's basically the work-around I used last week. And as a work-around it is tolerable. But it *really* seems like this should be something I can do with a WSUS report.